# Parsing XML data that has the same tag name but unique data

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

I'm trying to parse xml data into a list view in android, this is the xml result that i get when from the web service method, I want to get the value ref_num, summary, customer FOR EACH object, but they have the same tag name  and

```
   <UDSObjectList>
    <UDSObject>
    <Handle>cr:400047</Handle>
    <Attributes>
    <Attribute DataType="2002">
    <AttrName>ref_num</AttrName>
    <AttrValue>1</AttrValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute DataType="2002">
    <AttrName>summary</AttrName>
    <AttrValue>this is a summary</AttrValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute DataType="2005">
    <AttrName>customer</AttrName>
    <AttrValue>111111</AttrValue>
    </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    </UDSObject>
    <UDSObject>
    <Handle>cr:400040</Handle>
    <Attributes>
    <Attribute DataType="2002">
    <AttrName>ref_num</AttrName>
    <AttrValue>2</AttrValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute DataType="2002">
    <AttrName>summary</AttrName>
    <AttrValue>another summary</AttrValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute DataType="2005">
    <AttrName>customer</AttrName>
    <AttrValue>12123</AttrValue>
    </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    </UDSObject>
```

This is the code i use to parse it
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(theirID));

```
        Document doc = db.parse(is);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("UDSObject");

        // iterate the employees
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
           Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

           NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("AttrName");
           Element line = (Element) name.item(i);
           System.out.println("ID: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

           NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("AttrValue");
           line = (Element) title.item(i);
           System.out.println("ID Value: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));



           userID = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);


        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
.
.
.
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
        Node child = e.getFirstChild();
        if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
           CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
           return cd.getData();
        }
        return "?";
    }
```

When i run it, I only get the values for the FIRST object, how can i retrieve it for ALL objects and save the values  for each object in an ArrayList and display it into a list view

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns a list of nodes that are that tag, not it's contents. So in your case, it contains a list of UDSObjects. It looks like your code assumes it returns the children nodes.

Comment: @dandc87 so how can you fix it? any suggestions? thanks

Comment: you need to write some logic to retrieve those content from the list of nodes...